# Convert jstring to QString

Tags: android, c++, qt, qstring, qtandroidextras

I'm calling a Java function that returns a string:

```
QAndroidJniObject obj = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod<jstring>("HelloJava", "getString");
jstring jstr = obj.object<jstring>();
QString str = jstr; // This doesn't work, obviously, compiler-error.
```

And it returns a `jstring`, which is not very useful for me. How do I convert that to a `QString`, so I can use it in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [this method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#toString).

> QString QAndroidJniObject::toString() const
>
> Returns a QString with a string representation of the java object. Calling this function on a Java String object is a convenient way of getting the actual string data.

So, I would write this if I were you:

```
QAndroidJniObject string = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod<jstring>("HelloJava", "getString");

QString qstring = string.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

for converting `jstring` to `QString` you can use following lines:

```
static void onContactSelected(JNIEnv * env, jobject /*obj*/, jstring number)
{
    QString qstr(env->GetStringUTFChars(number, 0));
    /* .... some codes .... */
}
```

or in simple:

```
JNIEnv* env;
QString qstr(env->GetStringUTFChars(number, 0));
```

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-qt/qdlKrzi3mTQ)